# given 9 consecutive naturals, no partition into two sets will give set one product = set two product

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

I know another user already asked this but I want to do another approach.

Can we list the numbers as $y, y+1, y+2, y+3, y+4, y+5,y+6,y+7,y+8$ and go case by case

for the partition into a set with $8$ elements another set with $1$ element:

Say the element in the set with one element is $y+x_0$   (where $x_n$ is an integer less than nine and greater than or equal to zero)then select a integer in the other set directly below or above $y+x_0$ which gives:

$(y+x_1)(y+x_2)(y+x_3)....(y+x_7)=\frac{(y+x_8)}{y+x_0}$ and clearly $\frac{(y+x_8)}{y+x_0}$ is not an integer while the other side is. since $y+x_8$ is not divisible by $(y+x_0)$ as their difference is only $1$.

Can we expand this argument for other partitions like 4-5 partion?

This problem is from my Putnam book: Putnam and Beyond

Comment: I'd look at polynomial growth; this will put an upper bound on the number of solutions, which can be checked case-by-case. For instance, in the $(8,1)$ partition, you have a degree $8$ poly vs. a deg. $1$ poly. Similarly for each other partition (ex: in the $(5,4)$ case, you really only have to look at $(y)\cdots (y+4)$ and $(y+5)\cdots (y+8)$. The RHS is only larger for finitely many values.

Comment: You should give a link to the other posting of this problem, mathstudent.

Comment: See also P. Erdös and J. L. Selfridge, The product of consecutive integers is never a power, Illinois J. Math. 19 (1975), 292–301.

Comment: Makes no sense. Why is $y+x_8=\prod_{j=0}^7 (y+x_j)?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume we can partition the set of $9$ consecutive positive integers into two disjoint subsets with equal product. By the Pigeonhole Principle, one of the two disjoint subsets has atleast $5$ elements. The minimum product of the subset with atleast $5$ elements has product $\geqslant y(y+1)(y+2)(y+3)(y+4)$. It then follows that:
$$y(y+1)(y+2)(y+3)(y+4) \leqslant (y+5)(y+6)(y+7)(y+8)$$
Now, we know that the product of the nine consecutive positive integers is a square, and is divisible by $7$. Thus, it has to be divisible by $7^2$ forcing $y+8 \geqslant 14 \implies y \geqslant 6$. You can simply check that the above inequality does not hold when $y=6$, and thus will also not hold for any $y \geqslant 6$. This gives a contradiction, that proves the required claim.

Comment: Your displayed line is equivalent to $y^2+9y+9\le 201/y+1042/y^2+1680/y^3. $ If $y\ge 6$ then the LHS of this is at least $99$ and the RHS is less than $73.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You don't need to work that much to show it. Just check that it is wrong for $6$ and apply trivial induction.